Under epistemological pluralism, how can one determine the most suitable epistemology to apply in a given context?
According to Wikipedia:

Epistemological pluralism is a term used in philosophy, economics, and
virtually any field of study to refer to different ways of knowing
things, different epistemological methodologies for attaining a fuller
description of a particular field.[1] A particular form of
epistemological pluralism is dualism, for example, the separation of
methods for investigating mind from those appropriate to matter (see
mind–body problem). By contrast, monism is the restriction to a single
approach, for example, reductionism, which asserts the study of all
phenomena can be seen as finding relations to some few basic
entities.[2]
Epistemological pluralism is to be distinguished from ontological
pluralism, the study of different modes of being, for example, the
contrast in the mode of existence exhibited by "numbers" with that of
"people" or "cars".[3][4]
In the philosophy of science epistemological pluralism arose in
opposition to reductionism to express the contrary view that at least
some natural phenomena cannot be fully explained by a single theory or
fully investigated using a single approach.[1][5][6]
In mathematics, the variety of possible epistemological approaches
includes platonism ("mathematics as an objective study of abstract
reality, no more created by human thought than the galaxies") radical
constructivism (with restriction upon logic, banning the proof by
reductio ad absurdum and other limitations), and many other schools of
thought.[7]
In economics controversy exists between a single epistemological
approach to economics and a variety of approaches. "At midcentury, the
neoclassical approach achieved near-hegemonic status (at least in the
United States), and its proponents sought to bring all kinds of social
phenomena under its uniform explanatory umbrella. The resistance of
some phenomena to neoclassical treatment has led a number of
economists to think that alternative approaches are necessary for at
least some phenomena and thus also to advocate pluralism."[1] An
extensive history of these attempts is provided by Sent.[8]

The accepted answer to Is it epistemologically self-consistent to use the scientific method to justify some beliefs and non-scientific justifications for others? refers to the notion of pluralism in one's application of justificatory methods, which sounds like another way of saying epistemological pluralism:

You begin your question with the term 'epistemological self-consistency'. I believe that
such a term simply reduces to rationality, thus we can re-write,
particularly paraphrasing the latter half of the question:

Is it rational to use other forms of justification besides scientific justification?

The answer is an unqualified yes. It is absolutely rational to be pluralistic in one's application of justificatory methods. It makes
a lot of sense to perform mathematical justification in the domain of
mathematics, scientific justification in the domain of science,
economic justification in the domain of economics, etc. This naturally
carries to the logical end that it makes sense to use religious
justification in the domain of religion, a topic you seem highly
interested in reconciling with contemporary philosophical thinking.
The real thrust of your question is, if the epistemological success of science is so irrefutable, then shouldn't it essentially be applied to all domains of discourse? Here, you have broached the central concern of what constitutes the thinking of scientism.

Under epistemological pluralism, how does one determine the pool of epistemologies to choose from and identify the most appropriate one to apply in a given context? In other words, how can one justify the selection of epistemologies and the preference for one over another based on the context? Does this process require some form of meta-principle or meta-epistemology to compare and evaluate epistemologies?
For instance, one could argue that the scientific method has proven highly effective in many fields, yet history is not entirely amenable to scientific investigation since many historical events are non-repeatable. This might justify adopting a dual scientific/historical epistemology. However, a theist might contend that history can establish miracles in the past and that spiritual knowledge can be gained through sacred texts or mystical insights. It seems that arbitrarily choosing epistemologies could lead to arbitrarily accepting or rejecting claims, as one could always tailor their selection of epistemology to justify whatever they wish to believe. How can epistemological pluralism avoid this kind of arbitrariness?

It seems if there was any objectively right way to combine any two epistemologies on a given subject, that combination would already be a single epistemology. That which prevents any two epistemologies from being the same also prevents making an objective choice.

“Epistemologies” are human defined ways of gaining knowledge. You do not need to subscribe to an existing epistemology which is nothing more than an opinion of a person that isn’t any more valuable than yours just because he decided to spend years of his life writing a book on it. You have the freedom to choose whatever you think is appropriate. That’s how philosophy actually works

@Syed Sounds like you are saying all of philosphy is about gambling and judgement calls ;)

@user80226 indeed!

Check out American pragmatic philosopher Joseph Margolis, who was a pluralist and relativist. By relativist he meant that knowledge is inherently informal. Margolis opposed the Kantian notion that there is a determinate way of capturing cognitive judgments. Arguing that the informality of inquiry, of any kind, is best accounted for through an openness for relativistic veridiction. Give up foundationalism or "cognitive privilege" because cognitive questions generate "self-referential paradoxes" and that any determination in cognitive judgment has to make concessions to vagueness and reliance on "guess-work of many kinds."
The inevitable question arises: wouldn't relativism be self-contradictory? On this point, Margolis asserts that two positions must be granted from the outset to give legitimacy to his pluralistic relativism and so that it is not incoherent:
1)That the same proposition can be both true and false--a relativism that accepts this is not worth much;
2)That what is true, rightly understood, means "true for x" for some cognitive agent or other, but not otherwise. And what is true for x is "maybe true for y." Insoluble paradoxes emerge when one relativizes the application of the truth predicate such that you can never say that people hold different positions.
One has to admit truth-like values that are logically weaker than the binary values true-false. One has to allow for "reasonableness," "plausibility," or "aptness under these or those conditions," which will provide a basis for justifying "incompatibility" or "incommensurability." Only through many-valued logic can logic come out of its strait jacket and start to tackle the world as it is, rather than how we wish it to be.

Excellent answer, except that point 1 is not achievable for any pluralism.  IF one has multiple reference frames, they WILL lead to different conclusions.  This is seen in every science, where full internal consistency is not achieved to date in any of them (example, QM vs GR in physics -- they have yet to be reconciled).  Coherence is an impossible standard to meet.

+1 This advice also for me accords with both Quinian notions of ontological relativism and a neo-pragmatist claim that truth is mechanism that is wielded in accordance of the language community consensus particulary in the adoption of a plurality of logics.

The pluralism in this case refers to historical constructivism and the philosophy of culture. Logic, like science, is a product of historical and cultural processes. Like Ernst Cassirer or Bruno Latour, each symbolic form or mode of culture--religion, art, law, medicine, politics, etc.--has its own sphere of legitimacy and truth or validity. Different functioning norms establish different spheres of veridiction. He would certainly agree with you if we are discussing formalized logical semantics. Thank you
